# Atomically setting a variable without comparing first

Tags: atomic, cas

I've been reading up on and experimenting with atomic memory access for synchronization, mainly for educational purposes. Specifically, I'm looking at Mac OS X's `OSAtomic*` family of functions. Here's what I don't understand: Why is there no way to atomically *set* a variable instead of modifying it (adding, incrementing, etc.)? `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap*` is as close as it gets -- but only the swap is atomic, not the whole function itself. This leads to code such as the following not working:

```
const int N = 100000; 

void* threadFunc(void *data) {
    int *num = (int *)data;

    // Wait for main thread to start us so all spawned threads start
    // at the same time.   
    while (0 == num) { }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        OSAtomicCompareAndSwapInt(*num, *num+1, num);
    }
}

// called from main thread
void test() {
    int num = 0;

    pthread_t threads[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunc, &num);
    }

    num = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("final value: %d\n", num);

}
```

When run, this example would ideally produce 500,001 as the final value. However, it doesn't; even when the comparison in OSAtomicCompareAndSwapInt in thread X succeeds, another thread Y can come in set the variable first before X has a chance to change it.

I am aware that in this trivial example I could (and should!) simply use `OSAtomicAdd32`, in which case the code works. But, what if, for example, I wanted to set a pointer atomically so it points to a new object that another thread can then work with?

I've looked at other APIs, and they seem to be missing this feature as well, which leads me to believe that there is a good reason for it and my confusion is just based on lack of knowledge. If somebody could enlighten me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to check the `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapInt` result to guarantee that the `int` was actually set.